# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `company' for #<Model:0x007f96dcdea650>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have an issue with rails orm when i tried to get a field from a "belongs_to" model.

```
Processing by OdooHrDepartementController#index as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_odoo_link/app/views/odoo_hr_departement/index.html.erb within layouts/base (7.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 140.0ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `company' for #<OdooHrDepartement:0x007f96dcdea650>):
    14:   <tr>
    15:   <td class="username"><%= dp.create_date %></td>
    16:   <td class="firstname"><%= dp.name %></td>
    17:   <td class="lastname"><%= link_to dp.company.name , { :action => "show_companies", :id => dp.company_id }%></td>
    18:   <td class="email"><%= dp.note %></td>
    19:   <td class="email"><%= dp.OdooHrDepartement_id %></td>
    20:   <td class="email"><%= dp.OdooUsers_id %></td>
  activemodel (3.2.19) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
```

This is my view:

```
<h2>odoo departments</h2>

<table class="list">
  <thead><tr>
  <th>create date</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>company_id</th>
    <th>note</th>
    <th>parent_id</th>
    <th>manager_id</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
<% for dp in @departments -%>
  <tr>
  <td class="username"><%= dp.create_date %></td>
  <td class="firstname"><%= dp.name %></td>
  <td class="lastname"><%= link_to dp.company.name , { :action => "show_companies", :id => dp.company_id }%></td>
  <td class="email"><%= dp.note %></td>
  <td class="email"><%= dp.OdooHrDepartement_id %></td>
  <td class="email"><%= dp.OdooUsers_id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end -%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my  model:

```
class OdooHrDepartement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Company
  belongs_to :OdooHrDepartement
  belongs_to :OdooUsers 
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class OdooHrDepartementController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  def index
    @departments = OdooHrDepartement.all
  end

  def show_companies
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

there are my routes:

```
get 'odoo_departments', :to => 'odoo_hr_departement#index'
get 'odoo_departments/:id/' , :to => 'odoo_hr_departement#show_companies'
```

finally this is my migration code :

```
class CreateOdooHrDepartements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :odoo_hr_departements do |t|
      t.timestamp :create_date
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :company, index: true
      t.text :note
      t.belongs_to :OdooHrDepartement
      t.belongs_to :OdooUsers
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work.

Can someone please help me solve the error with the undefined method `company`?

Comment: `belongs_to :Company` should be `belongs_to :company`.

Comment: yes,, all belong should be downcased (it is rails style) or use `dp.Company`

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby uppercase identifiers are treated as constants. That means that you should ONLY use uppercase for constants such as class and module names and you guessed it - constants.

Other than that Ruby does not case what you name your methods, proterties and variables (or in the case of rails associations) but the convention is to always use snake_case. You are strongly recommended to follow it unless you like to look like a noob or have a very good reason not to (such as methods that mirror C functions or another external API).

```
class OdooHrDepartement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :odoo_hr_departement
  belongs_to :odoo_users 
end
```

Also if `Odoo` is the name of your company or app you might want to use a module to namespace your controllers and models instead of tacking it on the class name.

```
module Odoo
  class HrDepartementsController < ActiveRecord::Base

    def index
      @users = User.all # will lookup Odoo::User
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you should use identifiers in downcase.

Your `OdooHrDepartement` should look like this

```
class OdooHrDepartement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Company
  belongs_to :OdooHrDepartement
  belongs_to :OdooUsers 
end
```

and your migration should also use downcase for the associations

```
class CreateOdooHrDepartements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :odoo_hr_departements do |t|
      t.timestamp :create_date
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :company, index: true
      t.text :note
      t.belongs_to :odoo_hr_departement
      t.belongs_to :odoo_users
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure about whether `t.belongs_to :odoo_users` is correct or not because I don't know how you named your OdooUsers model.

I'd prefer using `references` in migrations, as e.g.

```
t.references :odoo_user, foreign_key: true
```

Same for `odoo_hr_department` and `company`.

Hope this helps.